# How to add/remove items in a state in react based on a toggle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a requirement to show products based on the checkbox toggles. If none is toggled, the array should be empty. If the men's checkbox is toggled, men-related products will be shown, and the same for the women's checkbox. If both are toggled, both related products will be shown. When the user is toggling men or women, the respective products are shown/hidden correctly, but something is messing up when toggling both men and women and getting a lot of console warnings related to react key. This is what I have tried so far.

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))

const initialArray = [
  {
    title: "Belts",
    for: "men"
  },
  {
    title: "Makeup",
    for: "women"
  }
];

function App() {
  const [menToggle, setMenToggle] = React.useState(false);
  const [womenToggle, setWomenToggle] = React.useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (menToggle) {
      setProducts((prev) => [
        ...prev,
        ...initialArray.filter((item) => item.for === "men")
      ]);
    }
    if (!menToggle) {
      setProducts((prev) => [...prev.filter((item) => item.for !== "men")]);
    }
    if (womenToggle) {
      setProducts((prev) => [
        ...prev,
        ...initialArray.filter((item) => item.for === "women")
      ]);
    }
    if (!womenToggle) {
      setProducts((prev) => [...prev.filter((item) => item.for !== "women")]);
    }
  }, [menToggle, womenToggle]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={menToggle}
          onChange={() => setMenToggle((prevValue) => !prevValue)}
        />
        Men
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={womenToggle}
          onChange={() => setWomenToggle((prevValue) => !prevValue)}
        />
        Women
      </label>
      <div>
        {products &&
          products.length > 0 &&
          products.map((item) => <li key={item.title}>{item.title}</li>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


root.render(<App />)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need to set the product's state every time the user changes the active filters because you can derive that value from the state. Also, I'd prefer to create a list of active filters rather than having each one in separated states. These filters tend to scale, and breaking them down can be hard to manage.

I came up with two solutions, one using `Array` and a "nicer" one using `Set`.

`Array`: https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-shape-inevid

`Set`: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-paper-mdw44m

Comment: I don't know much about this Set approach as it is not widely used. Is it good to use that, and how do I get started on learning the same?

Comment: Honestly, I think you should stick to the more common solution. A `Set` instance can give you very readable methods like `add`, `delete`, etc. However, other developers will understand the array approach more quickly because it is the standard approach. The best source for learning them is the MDN docs, I guess.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score -2):

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))

const initialArray = [
  {
    title: "Belts",
    for: "men"
  },
  {
    title: "Makeup",
    for: "women"
  }
];

function App() {
  const [menToggle, setMenToggle] = React.useState(false);
  const [womenToggle, setWomenToggle] = React.useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (menToggle) {
      setProducts((prev) => [
        ...prev,
        ...initialArray.filter((item) => item.for === "men")
      ]);
    }
    if (!menToggle) {
      setProducts((prev) => [...prev.filter((item) => item.for !== "men")]);
    }
    if (womenToggle) {
      setProducts((prev) => [
        ...prev,
        ...initialArray.filter((item) => item.for === "women")
      ]);
    }
    if (!womenToggle) {
      setProducts((prev) => [...prev.filter((item) => item.for !== "women")]);
    }
  }, [menToggle, womenToggle]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={menToggle}
          onChange={() => setMenToggle((prevValue) => !prevValue)}
        />
        Men
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={womenToggle}
          onChange={() => setWomenToggle((prevValue) => !prevValue)}
        />
        Women
      </label>
      <div>
        {products &&
          products.length > 0 &&
          products.map((item) => <li key={item.title}>{item.title}</li>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


root.render(<App />)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is my code. I don't see any changes

Comment: You just copied the code from the question - please try to be more helpful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).